# expected 'except' or 'finally' block

Tags: python

I am new in python
I try to understand "try expect" a simple code
but I have this msg in my terminal "expected 'except' or 'finally' block"
what does that mean
thank you

```
try:

    result=10/0
    value=input("enter a number")
    print("value")

expect  ZeroDivisionError :
    print("you cannot devide by zero ")

print("success")
```

Comment: After `try` you should use `except` not `expect` there is difference between them

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant?

Comment: If anyone wonders "Which PHP tag?": I removed 4 irrelevant tags. @MariamSaad It's kind of rude to add tags that have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3):

expect is not a keyword. `except` is.